# I can't access this website from home, but I can from everywhere else

Tags: networking, dns, domain-name

I think there's something wrong DNS-wise on my side.

I'm trying to visit this site:

```
http://goko.com/Dominion/gameClient.html
```

However, I'm getting DNS errors. If I try using the IP of the website:

```
http://8.31.166.14/Dominion/gameClient.html
```

It works but I can't actually do anything because the javascript is still loading from the domain. I know this website works as I've used other machine outside my network to access it.

What could be going wrong? Every other site works fine from my local network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your DNS settings and use 8.8.8.8 for your primary DNS and 8.8.4.4 for your secondary DNS.

This will use [Google's Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) servers.

Comment: That fixed it. Weird that my ISP's DNS couldn't find it while Google's did. I should have thought of this before.

Comment: That's always my default.  So far, no problems.

Comment: Cool, will accept in a couple minutes.

Comment: Thanks @slhck.  MaxMackie, as for why this is happening, I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: @Kruug Cool trick. Just learned something that's pretty interesting

Comment: -1 Google DNS has privacy issues.

Comment: @kinokijuf Well, I'm inclined to believe their official statement: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/faq#privacy